# GLSL Struct Array - Memory Allocation / Alignment

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I have a basic GLSL fragment shader with a struct array. I'd like to be able to determine the size of the array based on the machine running my program.

```
#version 410
#define MAX_DATA_SIZE %1

//32B (x8 FLOATS)
struct Data
{
    uint uintValue;//4B: 0
    float floatValue;//4B: 4
    sampler2D sampler;//16B: 5-8
};

uniform Data dataArray[MAX_DATA_SIZE];
```

The idea is:

- Read the value of GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS
- Divide the value by the size of my struct which is 8 in order to get the maximum size of my array
- Read the shader as a QString in QT and replace %1 by the calculated maximum size

My NVIDIA GPU runs ok.

The problem is with my Intel integrated GPU. When I update the array size based on what my Intel integrated GPU tells me (GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS return 4096/8 = 512), the application crashes seemingly running out of memory to allocate for the array.

It seems that the actual maximum array size is 32 for some reason and my Intel GPU is lying to me. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong here?

I know that UBOs would be a better option but I'm dealing with code that was written a while ago and converting it would take time. So I'm looking for a "HOT FIX" as you would call it.

Comment: "*the size of my struct which is 8*" That's not how component counts work. By the standard and ARB_bindless_texture, the component count of your struct is 4.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using bindless textures, sampler types don't count against component limits. So as far as GLSL proper is concerned, your struct takes up 2 components (each scalar only counts as one).

Instead, samplers count against the limit on the number of texture image units that a shader stage can use. Which on many (recent) pieces of Intel hardware is 32 for the fragment stage. Hence your array can't be bigger than 32.

Your NVIDIA implementation is probably silently treating those samplers as if you were using ARB/NV_bindless_texture. In which case, each sampler takes up two components, since they're treated as 64-bit integers. So your struct would take up 4 components.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm a bit confused by the component count though. 

Here is my current logic: 
When counting components you round up your count to a multiple of 4 (a vec4). So without the sampler, the count would be 2 rounded up to 4 and with the sampler it would still be 4. Or is that only used to calculate padding?

Comment: @rtavakko: "*Here is my current logic: When counting components you round up your count to a multiple of 4 (a vec4).*" Why would you do that? Where does it say that this rounding happens? Default block uniforms don't work like uniforms in UBOs.

Comment: Which if I understand correctly translates to "No, that's how you would do it for a UBO using the std140 layout". Thank you for your answer to the question.